# Flush stdin using fgets

Tags: objective-c, command-line, stdin, flush, fgets

Trying to make a registration page through the console.
I need several inputs for it, and I'm using fgets, so I need to flush stdin.
Lots of similar questions on Stack Overflow redirected here: http://c-faq.com/stdio/stdinflush2.html.
I got the code below using that link. However, this doesn't actually work. It says Username:, and then when I type in a username, and press enter, it just goes to a new, empty line in console where I can type in more.
Why is this happening?
How can I fix it?

EDIT: Added code

```
NSLog(@"Do you have an account already?(1 for Yes, 0 for no)");
    fgets(cnumb1, 2, stdin);
    int c;
    while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
    size_t length = strlen(cnumb1);
    if (cnumb1 [length-1] == '\n'){ // In case that the input string has 1 character plus '\n'
        cnumb1 [length-1] = '\0';} // Plus '\0', the '\n' isn't added and the if condition is false.
    NSString* string = [NSString stringWithUTF8String: cnumb1];
    if (string == 0) {
        while(numb4 == 1) {
            numb3 = 1;
            while( numb3 == 1){
                NSLog(@"Username:");
                fgets(usercheck1, 13, stdin);
                int c2;
                while((c2 = getchar()) != '\n' && c2 != EOF);
                size_t length1 = strlen(usercheck1);
                if (usercheck1 [length1-1] == '\n'){ // In case that the input string has 12 characters plus '\n'
                    usercheck1 [length1-1] = '\0';} // Plus '\0', the '\n' isn't added and the if condition is false.
```

Comment: If you use fgets you can forget about standard input buffer, you do't have to clean it.

Comment: In general yes, but only when the user enters less characters than the buffer can hold.

Comment: @onitake A while after I asked this I figured out that usercheck1 (which doesn't actually seem to be defined in this code) should be defined as char usercheck1 [large arbitrary number]

Answer (score 0):

*Completely rewrote my answer, looks like I didn't understand the problem well enough.*

The line that is supposed to empty the input buffer will not get anything until the user presses return again - unless the user enters more characters than the input buffer can hold.

You should first check the length of string read by `fgets` and if the last character (before the `\0`) is a `\n`, don't try to read more characters. Otherwise empty the input buffer like you did.

Comment: No matter how many returns, it doesn't do anything except move the blinking | cursor thing down another line. The point of that while line is that it is supposed to clear the stdin. I need this because if I don't, the next fgets just use the first input over and over, and I can only have that one input.

Comment: I see. However, if you try to do that, then you _will_ run into a flushing problem, as the shell will wait for the next newline until it gives you any characters. It seems a bit strange that you need to clear the input buffer though. `fgets` shouldn't give you anything you've already read before.

Comment: I have it search through the userInput4, and if it finds any spaces in there, it NSLogs it. Why does it give me that error if I type in "a"?

Comment: Putting a little more thought into it, you would get unwanted previous data if the user enters more characters than your buffer can hold. Those will obviously spill over to the next fgets...

Comment: I have a scanf before the fgets (I use scanf there just because it the user should only enter in a 1 or a 0), and when I type in "0" into the scanf, it skips the fgets and gives me the space error. o.O

Comment: Edited the answer with a suggestion.

Comment: Edited question with wider example, since I think that part is relevant.

Comment: Edited my answer again, with a (hopefully) much better suggestion.

Comment: Somehow it works now.... I think the problem was in the original was that the line from c-faq.com was BEFORE the fgets, while it was supposed to be after. EDIT: Its not working for strings longer then buffer. Edit in the c-faq.com is supposed to be after fgets for future readers please :)