# syscall read/write 1 byte only?

Tags: linux, assembly, buffer-overflow, arm64

I am new to assembly and trying to write a version of the "echo" built-in but only operating on 1 byte at a time.

I have the following which works the way I want, except it overflows more than 1 byte on both read and write even though I explicitly say 1 byte in x2 on both syscalls. What am I doing wrong?

Example run:

```
sh-4.2$ ./echo1b
f
f
o
o
b
b
bar
bar
bazbazbaz
bazbazbaz
q
sh-4.2$
```

Here is the code:

```
.data
temp:   .byte 1  

.text
.globl _start
_start:
    /* read one byte from stdin, store to temp */
    mov x0, #0x0
    adr x1, temp
    mov x2, #0x1
    mov x8, #0x3F
    svc #0x0

    /* write newline to stdout */
    mov x0, #0x1
    mov x1, #0xA
    mov x2, #0x1
    mov x8, #0x40
    svc #0x0
    
    /* if byte in temp is "q", exit */
    mov x5, #0x71
    ldr x1, temp
    cmp x1, x5
    beq exit

    /* otherwise, write it to stdout and repeat */
    mov x0, #0x1
    adr x1, temp
    mov x2, #0x1
    mov x8, #0x40
    svc #0x0
    b _start

exit:
    /* exit cleanly */  
    eor x0, x0, x0 
    eor x1, x1, x1
    eor x2, x2, x2
    mov x8, #0x5D
    svc #0x0
```

Comment: You are writing the newline wrong. `write` expects an address not a value. You need to do something like `newline: .byte 10` and then pass its address.

Comment: Incidentally, this is more like `cat` than `echo`.

Comment: @Jester Thanks! Even removing the entire newline section the read call is reading in much more than 1 byte and the write call at the bottom is writing it out. How can I limit those calls to just 1 byte (or x bytes) since the "count" field in x2 is not really doing anything.

Comment: what system is this running on? (syscalls are (operating) system specific)

Comment: They do process 1 each, but you have a loop. Note that input is line buffered. You might want to turn that off.

Comment: No, it is only reading one byte at a time and printing it. Then it loops and reads and prints another. If you fix the newline section instead of removing it, you will see that.

Comment: ... or run it under `strace ./my_program`, or under a debugger.

Comment: @old_timer arm64

Comment: @Jester Thanks again.

Comment: That is not a system that is a high level (marketing type) term that at best indicates an instruction set.  There can be hundreds (well unlimited)(incompatible) different system call definitions that apply to the term arm64.  To make the question complete and not require guessing or assumptions you need to be clear.

Comment: Some percentage of the system call/software interrupt issues on SO is the OP is using  a call reference that does not match the system, thus the need to ask a clear/complete question.

Comment: @old_timer ubuntu server 20.04 LTS 64-bit running on a raspberry pi 4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several issues in your code:

- As mentioned in the comments, the output buffer's address has to be in `x1` when calling `sys_write` as you did with `temp`
- When comparing `temp` with the newline character, you had to use `ldrb w1, [x0]` instead of `ldr x1, temp` where `x0` points to `temp`. The latter would read 4 bytes while it's not guaranteed that the upper three bytes are zero.

I also improved some parts of your code:

- `cmp` can be used with a 12 bit immediate so there's no need to put `0x71` in a register.
- Moving the second `sys_write` call before `_start` avoids the unconditional jump.
- `sys_exit` uses only `x0` as parameter so there's no need to set `x1` and `x2` to zero.

Here's the final code, tested on Raspbian 4.19 (debian based):

```
.data
    temp:    .byte 1
    newline: .byte 0x0A

.text
.globl _start

loop:
    // 4: Otherwise, write it to stdout and repeat
    mov  x0, #0x1    // int    fd
    adr  x1, temp    // void*  buf
    mov  x2, #0x1    // size_t count
    mov  x8, #0x40   // sys_write
    svc  #0x0
    
_start:
    // 1: Read one byte from stdin and store to temp (including newline)
    mov  x0, #0x0   // int    fd
    adr  x1, temp   // void*  buf
    mov  x2, #0x1   // size_t count
    mov  x8, #0x3F  // sys_read
    svc  #0x0
    
    // 2: If byte in temp is 'q', exit
    adr  x0, temp
    ldrb w1, [x0] // instead of temp
    cmp  x1, #0x71
    bne  loop

    // 5: Exit cleanly
    eor  x0, x0, x0  // int status
    mov  x8, #0x5D   // sys_exit
    svc  #0x0
```

**Edit after comment:** To flush stdin at exit, you could add this lines before step 5:

```
    // 5: Flush stdin (read until newline)
flush:
    mov  x0, #0x0   // int    fd
    adr  x1, temp   // void*  buf
    mov  x2, #0x1   // size_t count
    mov  x8, #0x3F  // sys_read
    svc  #0x0

    adr  x0, temp
    ldrb w1, [x0]
    cmp  x1, #0x0A
    bne flush       // loop until x0 == 0x0A
```

Comment: Thank you so much, super helpful. One more question if you have time, with this code and the code above if "q" is in the beginning or middle of the line buffer it will flush the whole line out to stdout (and assume it's a command.). How would you recommend flushing the buffer so it doesn't do that?

Comment: There is no `fflush` command at assembly level. As mentioned in [stdin using fgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17621258/flush-stdin-using-fgets) you could read until newline to achieve this. I added some code to my answer that does that.

Comment: @Sk6: If you want to read stdin up to EOF, you can do it much more efficiently with a larger buffer.  In theory it might take more than 1 `read` syscall if input was redirected from a large file, but from a terminal it's likely that one 4k read would get everything.  (If less data is available, `read` returns with a smaller count.)  I'd call this "draining" stdin; flushing makes more sense for output streams.  What happens if you don't do this is that later bytes stay unread, still in the kernel's buffer for that file (tty), so the shell reads it when your program exits.

Comment: Of course, if you want to drain stdin when you exit, there's no need to do something as inefficient as reading 1 byte at a time.  In your input loop, you can read into a larger buffer, then loop over the number of bytes read, interleaving with `\n`, and do one large `write`.  (AArch64 has SIMD so you can do the interleaving very efficiently, 8->16 bytes at a time, with [`vzip.8`](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0489/i/neon-and-vfp-programming/vzip) or something.)

Comment: (That link was for 32-bit ARM.  AArch64 uses slightly different naming for its SIMD instructions.)